# How to pass data in Django via hyperlink in a table

Tags: python, django, hyperlink, param

I want to display a list of objects in a table, no problem doing the table. I want to put links in the data displayed of one column in the template. The question is, how can I pass data in that link to the view?. For example in struts2 and JSPs, I used to do it this way (with param):

```
<td class="nowrap">
                    <s:url id="unitList" action="doSubject!ShowSubjectUnits">
                    <s:param name="subjectID" value="%{id}" />
                    </s:url>
                    <s:a href="%{unitList}"><s:text name="%{unidades.size()}"/></s:a>
</td>
```

Comment: I don't care about struts, whatever it is. What is the intended output? What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can simply add GET parameters to your url:

```
<a href="{% url view-name %}?subjectID={{id}}">your link</a>
```

Even better would be a [nice url design](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) with arguments:

```
<a href="{% url path.to.some_view subjectid=id action=action %}">your link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you!, If I have many paramaters, for example 7, is there an alternative way to do it? for example inserting  in POST method?